# Complexity of $Th(\langle \mathbb{N},= \rangle)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computational-complexity

I can prove that the decision problem of $Th(\langle \mathbb{N},= \rangle)$ is PSPACE-hard. However, the recursive algorithm to show it is in PSPACE would not work, since variables are unbounded and unrelated to the formula size.

Is there a more precise complexity classification for this theory?

Comment: Note that equality-only sentences have the finite model property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences in the empty language (= equality-only - I'm adopting the modern convention that equality is a logical predicate) have the **finite model property** in a very nice way: if $\varphi$ is a sentence in the empty language of length $n$, then the following are equivalent:

- $\varphi$ is true in a pure set of size $n$.
- $\varphi$ is true in every pure set of size $\ge n$.

This is proved by induction on formula complexity (really we just need to count *variables occurring in* $\varphi$ rather than its full length, but meh).

It's now easy to show that checking whether an equality-only sentence of length $n$ is satisfied in a pure set of size $k$ can be performed in space polynomial in $\max\{n,k\}$. This gives a $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ upper bound to your question (so we get $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-completeness).

Comment: What do you mean by "pure set" in this context?

Comment: @RobArthan Set without any additional structure - in other words, an $\emptyset$-structure (in the context of first-order logic with equality).

Comment: I see (I have only come across the term in connection with ZF, where it means something different). It would be nice if you could give a reference or a proof for this strong finite model property.